# Visitors to city's website can digitize points?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to collect input on a revision to my town's mainstreet.  Is it possible to create a map where a visitor can click a point, and answer a few questions about that point?  (OK I was told that this question is too broad, so I am going to try to refine it)

Essentially, I want to be able to embed this map on the city's website, then invite community members to visit it and place markers at points on Main Street that they either like/dislike.  Ideally they would be able to drag a red or a green marker onto the map, which prompts one or two questions about the site, then move on.

I expect this could be done many different ways, but I really don't even know where to start looking for a solution.

Comment: The short answer is "yes", but the long answer is too long for here.

Comment: OK, well, that's encouraging.  Can you point me in a direction?  I don't even know if this is a javascript issue, or a leaflet thing or maybe Google Maps API?  I'm hoping for something simple, since I am a map person, but not a code person.  Thanks.

Comment: It is because "this could be done many different ways" that this question is too broad.  I recommend taking one of the options that you are considering and exploring whether that meets your requirements.  That way you will be able to describe what you have tried and where you are stuck to make your question more focussed.

Comment: I'm asking for help figuring out an approach to this problem.  If I knew how I wanted to do it, I wouldn't be asking this question.  I would be asking a narrower more technical question.  I don't know what else to say.  I currently use CartoDB and Google for hosting web maps that display my own data.  I'm trying to enter the world of true interactive maps, where visitors contribute information... and avoid spending two weeks figuring out MySQL only to discover that I should've been learning JSON, or whatever.  How would YOU approach this challenge?

Comment: Are "community members" authenticated and logged in before they can click on things? What data about the click is stored? Is it referenced to the community member? Are all the collected markers visible on a member's map, or none, or just theirs? Or is it all open to the public to click anywhere? Any JS mapping tool can play its part in this (leaflet, OpenLayers) and any backend DB (MySQL, PostGIS...). Pick one and try. Oh, I'll choose for you. leaflet and PostGIS.

Comment: Something like this? http://users.leafletjs.com/ (click "Add Me To The Map" button at top)

Comment: Hey.  Sorry for absence, was in the field last week.  To answer your questions...  No, I don't want users to have to sign in to anything.  I want the bar for contributing to be a low as possible.  I would like the points to be visible to everyone, but I could also be OK if each user was blind to the others.  OK, Leaflet and PostGIS.  The map you posted is very similar to the one I'm interested in, just different questions, photo upload option and multiple pin-drops.  I also anticipate wanting a mobile version too, eventually.

Comment: Polygeo.  I appreciate the primer on web-mapping, but this isn't really a duplicate of that question.  I'm asking specifically about maps that users can contribute to.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with a tool called [LocalData](http://localdata.com/).

Basically you create a form and it builds a page that users consume in a mobile app.

The results go into a online database in your account, and you can do with it what you want from there!

I believe they are not integrated with CartoDB, but you can download your data into various geospatial / tabular formats.

There are tools from ESRI called Collector if you want to go that route.

Comment: Thanks, I just visited the LocalData site, it looks like it could be a good fit but is still in testing phase?

Comment: @Cameron no I think they've matured beyond that... I think they're only problem is finding a big enough market for their tools...